# How can I add the values of If and Else in two different lists, using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
even = []
odd = []
lst = []

for i in range(1, 21):
    lst.append(i)
```

To find even or odd

```
for i in lst:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(i)
    else:
        odd.append(i)

print(even, odd)
```

Is there any pythonic way of doing it using list comprehension, where the output values of 'if and else' condition must be saved in two different lists.

Comment: You can filter the list twice with LC and create two lists

Comment: Why? I mean, you could do everything in one traversal by using `reduce` and side-effects: `reduce((lambda xs, i: xs[i%2].append(i) or xs), lst, ([], []))`, similar things can be obtained *abusing* list-comprehensions with side-effects but *these are **not** more pythonic, they are only harder to read*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
odd=[]
even=[]
[even.append(i) if i%2==0 else odd.append(i) for i in xrange(1,21)]
```

You can do this using `if else`.

Comment: If you really want to use hacks why not `[[even,odd][i%2].append(i) for i in xrange(1,21)]`?

Answer (score 2):

For a simple solution, you could do something like this:

```
odds = [i for i in range(1,21) if i % 2 == 0]
even = [i for i in range(1,21) if i % 2 != 0]
```

---

Other people have provided some nice one liners.

Answer (score 1):

Think this is what @fourtheye mentioned in his comment..

```
>>> el,ol = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, range(1, 21)),filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, range(1, 21))
>>> el
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
>>> ol
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple solution.

```
>>> lst = range(1,21)
>>> odd = range(1,21,2)
>>> even = range(2,21,2)
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
>>> even
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

> range(start, stop[, step])
>
> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops

Answer (score 0):

Hardly pythonic, and slow, but still possible in a single expression involving a couple of list comprehensions and a zip.  Something like:

```
odds, evens = [[y for y in x if y is not None] for x in zip(*[(x, None) if x % 2 else (None, x) for x in range(1, 21)])]
```

Breaking that down ... we construct a list of tuples where the first item is a number if its odd, and None otherwise; and the second item is a number if it is even, or None otherwise.

```
[(x, None) if x % 2 else (None, x) for x in range(1, 21)]
```

We unzip that into two lists of odds and evens ... unfortunately it contains all the Nones as well

```
zip(*[(x, None) if x % 2 else (None, x) for x in range(1, 21)])
```

So we filter them out with the `[y for y in x if y is not None]`